# JCifs login failure on windows to linux file transfer

Tags: java, linux, authentication, jcifs

The following code working correctly on from windows to windows file tranfer but when i use this code in linux (for from windows to linux file transfer) i get errors.

```
Error:
```

jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

```
String user = "username",
    pass = "password",
    path = "smb://192.168.1.195/path/file.txt";

   try {        
       NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", user, pass);
       SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);               
       InputStream stream = new SmbFileInputStream(smbFile);
       ...

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Full stack trace would be useful

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are attempting to login to a Linux machine using Windows credentials. `NtlmPasswordAuthentication` is only used by Windows, not Linux. This works going from Linux to Windows because it is correctly converting the password to the form in which Windows can authenticate it. However, when you try to do Windows to Linux, it is producing an incorrect value.

Comment: I used this sample for authentication [that](http://beytullahc.blogspot.com.tr/2014/09/java-smbsamba-protokolu-ile-dosya.html) and he said that this app works cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is below;

```
    String user = "username" + ":" + "password";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
    String path = "smb://" + filePath;
    SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
```

Example:
[File upload and Download Using Smb protocol](http://beytullahc.blogspot.com.tr/2014/09/java-smbsamba-protokolu-ile-dosya.html)